# Ошибка при отправке post запроса API компании "Ephor". {"success":false,"code":0,"message":"Wrong POST request data format."}

Tags: python, api, requests

Ошибка при отправке post запроса компании "Ephor". Для того, чтобы получать ответы после запроса, нужно отправить логин-запрос по ссылке "http://erp.ephor.online/api/2.0/Auth.php", а также параметры: action = Login, _dc = 1518591517187, login и password, где action - команда, которую сервер должен выполнить, а _dc - "Уникальный идентификатор запроса. Лучше всего
использовать текущее время в секундах. Необходим для защиты от повторяющихся
запросов."

```
import requests
import time

SERVER = 'http://erp.ephor.online'
path_to_login = '/api/2.0/Auth.php'

params = {
    "action": 'Login',
    '_dc': 1518591517187,
    # '_dc': int(str(time.time()).split('.')[0]), этот вариант так же не работает
    'login': '****',
    'password': '****'
}

req = requests.post(SERVER + path_to_login, data=params)
print(req.text)
```

После команды print приходит данное сообщение: "message: Wrong POST request data format". Ссылка к документации - https://erp.ephor.online/download/apiv2.pdf

Comment: time_zone число Смещение часового пояса (по умолчанию -3) - Москва. Страница 13. То что вы пытаетесь передать, используется при запросе конфигурации или изменении данных.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вы имеете в виду, что мне надо изменить метод post на get или добавить в словарь параметр time_zone? И то, и другое никак не влияет, пробовал(

Comment: Вы выполняете аутентификацию. На странице 13 руководства написано, что при выполнении Auth.php передается параметр time_zone, по умолчанию равный 3. То есть Москве. Вы можете передать значение вашей временной зоны. Для примера: 4. Если я все правильно понял. Вы же пытаетесь передать параметр от другого метода: Config.php

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, поменялся лишь ответ
#0 /var/www/html/ephor_erp/server/lib/action/DatabasePost.php(38): ActionJsonPost->procPostData('action=Login&_d...')
#1 /var/www/html/ephor_erp/server/lib/action/Database.php(60): ActionDatabasePost->procData()
#2 /var/www/html/ephor_erp/server/lib/action/Processor.php(58): ActionDatabase->proc()
#3 /var/www/html/ephor_erp/api/2.0/Auth.php(250): Ephor\ActionProcessor->proc()
#4 /var/www/html/ephor_erp/server/lib/core/Map.php(91): require_once('/var/www/html/e...')